# How to efficiently find a small logo in an image

Tags: image-processing, opencv, scaling, histogram

I am trying to fine tune my image detection project and through my various tests I seem to hit a snag. If I have a logo that is small, (around 10x15), in an image my detection seems to fail and bypass it. I tried to manually crop that logo and upscale it to different resolutions, but the up-scaling causes too much noise and distorts the logo. I tried the reverse method as well by taking the logo from the image and use it to test with, thinking it should pick it up being a 1-1 comparison, however it had reverse side effects of finding too many matches in the image.

I am using SIFT with affine transformations, and color calibration with histograms to detect my other matches. I've tried sharpening an image after up-scaling it, but that didn't work well either.

Is there anything that I could test or implement that would detect the logo? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Including two different sets of tests that I ran where it failed.

Nike:

[image: Nike Logo]

Image to test logo on (Trying to get it off the collar):

[image: Player collar]

Apple:

[image: Apple Logo]

Image to test on (Cannot find enough matches to register a hit):

[image: Mac Cover]

Comment: Please post an example of the original logo and your image to analyze what could be happening there

Comment: I've edited my post to include two logos that I've tested with that came up with little to no matches.

Comment: Mmmm I tried a few standard algorithms with your first image. It seems  that the resolution is too low to identify the little logo

Comment: What algorithms did you use and do you have any advice on what to do if the resoulution is too low or if the image doesn't have enough features to make a proper match?

Comment: I first tried Sift and Surf, without getting good results, mainly because the feature in the logo are not being detected properly in the image due to the lack of resolution. Then I tried a combination of several edge detection algs, followed by a convolution with a Gaussian kernel and then a parametrized affine transform, but the edges are not being detected well enough or this approach in the image. Answering your ask for advice, I don't think the problem is "lack of features", but "lack of resolution". cont-

Comment: In these cases usually a two step approach is better (and harder): try to relax the matching conditions in SURF, and you'll get false positives. Then inspect the matches by another method (color histogram matching, for example) and reduce the matching set. A third filter could by needed too!

Comment: I tried to blow up the image, but it was so distorted that nothing would pick up or too many matches would pick up that were invalid. Is there any way to sharpen these properly?

Comment: @Sep i don't think so. You can't create information that isn't there. Sorry.

Comment: Your images suffer not only from lack of resolution but also distortions due to compression.  The Nike

Comment: Keep in mind that at a certain scale, this problem becomes intractable. Think about all the tiny areas in the baseball image that actually fit a tiny Nike swoosh; edges of letterforms, specular highlights, etc.  Humans can identify the true swoosh because they first identified the guy wearing the shirt, so it becomes a machine learning problem instead of an image processing problem. I'm not saying you cant improve, but there is a limit.

Comment: I don't think you will have any luck with the first image at least: consider that the curve of the shirt has actually distorted the logo so that it bends to the left instead of the right at the start of the swoosh. Any machine detection loose enough to find that is probably going to have a ton of false positives.

Comment: @zephyr: There has to be some way to be able to detect that while keeping the number of false positives low.

Comment: @Seb I don't think you're likely to find one. Basically all there is to go on is a thin slanted white blob on a black background. In this case, the angle is similar, but what if he was leaning over? Or what if the color could vary, then some of those mouths would look just as valid. The only way our eyes can pick it out is because of our contextual recognition of the shirt as an object of clothing, and that's something that will be very difficult to teach a computer.